How to use SpringBoot Actuator HealthIndicator without exposing any endpoint?
I am trying to write my own endpoints to return SpringBoot Actuator liveness and readiness status over /ready, /live and /health without exposing any default endpoint from Actuator dependency.
When setting management.endpoints.web.exposure.exclude=*, my code refering to HealthEndpoint class prevents the app from starting.
Is there a way to use HealthEndpoint class without actually exposing anything?
Or is there a way to retrieve liveness and readiness health status without HealthEndpoint?
I've tried to inject HealthIndicator livenessState and readinessState to no avail, I've had an error saying that 4 dependencies were injected instead of 1.
I've tried playing with exclude and include settings to no avail.

May be you can try below configurations:

Disable all endpoints by default


management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false


Enable and expose only the /health endpoint


management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health


By default readiness and liveness probe are disabled and can be unable by property:


management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true

